# Atlassian JSD plugin development (dependencies and plugins cannot be found)

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm new to the Atlassian development and I've went over the guides/tutorials for plugin development and everything worked fine (I'm using Ubuntu with IntelliJ as IDE). Also read the "Jira 7 Development Cookbook - Third Edition". When I tried to switch to JSD development the dependencies and plugins didn't work. I get errors like this:

```
Dependency : 'com.atlassian.jira.plugins:project-templates-api:2.18' not found
```

or

```
Plugin : 'com.atlassian.plugin:atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin:2.0.1' not found
```

I'm following [guides from the official site](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-applications/jira-service-desk/jira-service-desk-development-guide) under that part of the development guides. I've looked over documentation of API plugins and classes and tried changing the version and/or name of the plugins, but I always get that same error. Have I overlooked something important or is this something that happens often and has a solution?

EDIT:

Don't use

```
 atlas-mvn idea:idea
```

as drelliot said. 
You have to add dependencies and plugins manually on pom.xml and do

```
 atlas-mvn install
```

I still have bugs, but most were solved by this.

Comment: Can you add the steps you took to start working on JSD development? What changed between when it was working and when it stopped working? Also, what happens when you run `atlas-mvn clean` and `atlas-mvn install` in your plugin directory? Have you added the Atlassian Maven repo as the default for intellij for your project?

Also, for the atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin try version 1.2.13

Comment: Greetings, I've used atlas-create-jira-plugin to create a project and started adding dependencies in pom.xml. After that I made a class and noticed it doesn't recognize the import of the package, so I tried atlas-mvn clean/atlas-mvn install and atlas-mvn idea:idea. When I run atlas-mvn clean and atlas-mvn install the build succeeds, but on atlas-mvn idea:idea it fails with this error : "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-idea-plugin:2.3-atlassian-10:idea (default-cli) on project.... NullPointerException". The same happens when I change the version to 1.2.13.

Comment: Can you post a pastebin or something with the full output of mvn idea:idea?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T3ENUg8j <--- atlas-mvn idea:idea -X output

Comment: I think the maven idea plugin is retired - why are you using it?

Comment: The official tutorials on atlassian say that you can use any IDE, so I use intelliJ as I prefer it over eclipse, but I've tried eclipse also and it gives me errors in it, it's not just in intellij.

Comment: You don't need to run that plugin anymore, all you need to do is run `atlas-create...` and import the folder into intellij. If you want the API jars to resolve you can add specific versions of the dependencies into the pom.xml and run `atlas-mvn install` , then import changes into the maven project and you're good to go. idea:idea is not required.

Comment: Thanks for help, the tutorials are really outdated and not really good, you helped.

Comment: No worries! happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
atlas-mvn idea:idea
```

as drelliot said. You have to add dependencies and plugins manually on pom.xml and do

```
atlas-mvn install
```

After that just import the project into IDE of your choice. I still have bugs with packages and version since the official tutorials are outdated and don't help a lot, but most were solved by this.